# How can you view generated class files?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, decompiling, decompiler

Using Android Studio, I'm trying to learn more about what goes on under the hood.  One of those things is code-generation.

For instance, when you define a nested enum in your code like this...

```
class EnumExample1
{
    public enum Season
    {
        WINTER,
        SPRING,
        SUMMER,
        FALL
    }
}
```

According to [this tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/enum-in-java), the compiler generates this...

```
public static final class EnumExample1$Season extends Enum  
{  
    private EnumExample1$Season(String s, int i)  
    {
        super(s, i);  
    }  

    public static EnumExample1$Season[] values()  
    {  
        return (EnumExample1$Season[])$VALUES.clone();  
    }  

    public static EnumExample1$Season valueOf(String s)  
    {  
        return (EnumExample1$Season)Enum.valueOf(EnumExample1$Season, s);  
    }  

    public static final EnumExample1$Season WINTER;  
    public static final EnumExample1$Season SPRING;  
    public static final EnumExample1$Season SUMMER;  
    public static final EnumExample1$Season FALL;

    private static final EnumExample1$Season $VALUES[];  

    static   
    {
        WINTER = new EnumExample1$Season("WINTER", 0);  
        SPRING = new EnumExample1$Season("SPRING", 1);  
        SUMMER = new EnumExample1$Season("SUMMER", 2);  
        FALL.  = new EnumExample1$Season("FALL", 3);  

        $VALUES = new EnumExample1$Season[]
        {  
            WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL  
        };
    )
}
```

This is really helpful on understanding exactly what's going on.  As such, I'm trying to see how various other things are compiled down, but I can't seem to find anything about how to get to anything resembling this source code.  My guess is that I'm going to have to decompile a generated '*.jar' file, but that's purely a guess (although I'd like to believe it's at least a somewhat-educated one.)

So how can you view compiler-generated code based on your own?

Comment: There should be a directory `build > intermediates > classes > debug > mypackage.foo.bar > myclass.class`. Your IDE will be able to it.

Comment: Maybe its just an example, but just FYI there's no reason to have your enum inside another class. `public enum Season` can live in its own file perfectly happily (the filename needs to match, as usual, so it would need to be in `Season.java`)

Comment: It doesn't need to, but for encapsulation purposes, it should be nested in some cases.  Either way, as you correctly assumed, this is for illustrative purposes.  Plus, if it wasn't nested, I don't believe the generated code would have made it 'static' which is one of the reasons to choose this as an example.

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing what you're referring to.  Can you elaborate more, but better yet, put it in an answer, perhaps with a screenshot showing where that is? After all, I can't 'accept' a comment! :)

Comment: I don't have a copy of Android Studio installed on this PC, so I couldn't be certain on the exact directories - I'm working from memory. You should be able to navigate to your project directory in e.g. Windows Explorer and find the structure I'm talking about. Or just search for files ending in `.class`. I'll double check all this when I get home later, if you still don't have an answer.

Comment: Just checked the path you said, but it doesn't exist on my machine.  In 'intermediates' I only see 'dev-cache', and in there there's only 'cache.xml'.  That said I think I'll take you up on your order to check when you get back home. Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, not sure if this matters, but I'm on a Mac.  Additionally, I thought I read somewhere that you had to add something to your gradle to allow this, no?